# How to append div at a certain place present in another component

Tags: jquery

This is how my screen looks (each Checkbox has corresponding values):

On click of a checkbox , i am creating a div and adding it to the main Orders div as shown below .

```
$(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function (e) {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        var buildcart = $('<div id="addtoordersdiv"></div>');
                      buildcart.append('<div  data-role="collapsible">
                      <div class="prd-items-detials">
                      <ul><li class="head">
                      <form><label class="testtt" for="checkbox-mini-0">' + itemname + '</label></form>
                      </li><li class="prd-items-qt">
                      <div class="col"><span class="prd-sm-img">
                      <img id="imagesd" type="img" height="40" width="40"  src="'+image+'"/>
                      <span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col"><i class="minus"></i>
                      <i class="qt qt_'+id_attr_val+'">1</i>
                      <i class="plus" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'"></i>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col">
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">Topping</a></div>
                      <div style="display: none;" class="price" >'+price+'</div>
                      <div class="col total total_'+id_attr_val+'" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'">'+price+'</div></li></ul>
                      </div>
                      // add it right after here 
                      </div>');

        var dataa = '<div id="ordersdiv" style="display:none"></div>';
        $("#myordersdiv ul").append(dataa);
        $("#ordersdiv").prepend(buildcart);

    $("#myordersdiv").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#ordersdiv').remove();
          $('#addtoordersdiv').remove();

    }
});
```

When clicked on the Honey with Choclate Sauce 10 ML (a href values)

I have got one more listener which gets activated when clicked on the section content

```
$(document).on("click", ".secclass a", function (e) {
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var topping='<div class="Topping-details"><section><a href="#">Honey With Choclate Sauce 10ML</a></section></div>';
$( this ).addClass( "tpActive" );
});
```

My question is that when i clcik on the secclass element , is it possible to append the data variable called topping to the 'add it right after here' place   present inside the checkboxclas listener ??

Could anybody please help .

Comment: You should not use same id for multiple elements. Use class instead.

Comment: Can you crop that image down to just the relevant part?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar This girl is adamant in this, we suggested that many times..!

Comment: @PreethiJain Please create a fiddle and explain your problem specifically by writing down what you have tried and what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(this).parent().next('.col').after(topping);
```

Comment: Thanks , you mean , i need to add the this line after this statement $( this ).addClass( "tpActive" ); ??

Comment: Yes you can. just after declaring topping

Comment: This is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/R7Cwg/ (as the data is coming from the databsase , it is not working currently .)

Comment: just put the static html instead.